# handlebars include partial in index

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm just trying to use handlebars in a project. So I have a PartialNavigation.handlebars and index.handlebars, and I just want to include the PartialNavigation to index with one parameter. I was checking the docs since a long time but didn't found what I want. And all I tried failed...

Thanks per advance!

PokeRwOw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Handlebars, you can register your partial using the `Handlebars.registerPartial()` method.

Example:

```
var partialNavData = '<div id="navigation"></div>';

Handlebars.registerPartial( 'partialNavigation', partialNavData );
```

Registering multiple partials at once:

```
var partialNavData = '<div id="navigation"></div>';    
var partialFooterData = '<footer>My Footer</footer>';

Handlebars.registerPartial({
    partialNavigation: partialNavData,
    partialFooter: partialFooterData
});
```

And finally, including your partials would be done like so:

Your index file:

```
{{>partialNavigation}}

{{>partialFooter}}
```

** You can use AJAX to grab the PartialNavigation template if it's too large to put into a string.

Example JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/richardgirges/Lkrn1qLL/3/

Read [these reference docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/reference.html) for more info

Comment: I followed step by step and I got this error : "The partial partialNavigation could not be found"

Comment: Can you paste your Handlebars.registerPartial line?

Comment: I just put your example with partialNavData in PartialNavigation.handlebars and call {{>partialNavigation}} in the index file

Comment: Can you take an example with 2 files (PartialNavigation and index) please ?